# Multiple insertion with same input name in php

Tags: php, mysql

thank you for your answer meanwhile i got this code for inserting the multiple data, and it really works but my problem is it adds the fisrt column then after finished then it executes the second column i want them to excecute insert f1 then f2 then f1 then f2 again:
just imagine i have 4 input with same name f1 and f2

[Inserting multiple entries into table from the same form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779708/inserting-multiple-entries-into-table-from-the-same-form) please refer on this post

Comment: There's multiple things wrong here, but most importantly, none of your form fields have a `name` attribute, and that attribute will be needed to pass information to your PHP script to be used in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing names in all of your form fields

```
/*PHP code where the form submit, and repeat the same for other fields like descriptionField*/



 <?php
   for($i = 0; $i <= count ( $_POST ['dateField'] ); $i ++) {
    // Do what ever you want with data
    var_dump ( $_POST ['dateField'] [$i] );
    }

    ?>
```

HTML Code, names added

```
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr">
                <textarea>Date</textarea>
                <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
            </div></td>

        <td class="description"><textarea name="descritpionField[]">Description</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="dateField[]" style="text-align: center;"
                class="asd">0</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="dateField[]" style="text-align: center;"
                class="qty">0</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="dateField[]" style="text-align: center;"
                class="cost">0</textarea></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><span class="price">0</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly

If this fields in form, then set 'name' attr to fields like name="user[]"
When u'll submit the form, all values of "user[]" fields will in array. Just do print_r() and you will see, what i try to explain

Also u can do it in javascript. . .
Just grab all values in array. . .

User "Noor" already post example for you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
  <?php

  echo "<pre>";
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      print_r($_POST['data']);//RESULT WILL GET AN ARRAY

  }

  ?>

  <form action="" method="post">
  <table>
  <?php
  //$items = // DATA FROM DB
  //$items_count = count($items);
  $items_count = 5;
  for($i=0;$i<$items_count;$i++) {
      ?>
      <tr class="item-row-<?php echo $i;?>">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['date']">Date</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['description']">Description</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['age']" style="text-align:center;" class="asd">0</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['dob']" style="text-align:center;" class="qty">0</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea name="data[<?php echo $i;?>]['status']" style="text-align:center;" class="cost">0</textarea></td>
          <td style="text-align:center;" ><span class="price">0</span></td>
      </tr>

  <?php } ?>
  <table>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer fo the post (Trouble with $_POST [duplicate])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238124/trouble-with-post)

I don't know if I understand your concern.
I think you are trying to create a quiz. And so the user must validate several attempts. your problem is that you can not accumulate the different answers following a table. so here is a solution.

```
<?php

$good_answers = array(
    "easy1" => array("4","3","5","2","6","9","7","8","1" ),
    "easy2" => array("6","8","2","5","7","1","4","9","3" ),
    "easy3" => array("1","9","7","8","3","4","5","6","2" ),
    "easy4" => array("8","2","6","1","9","5","3","4","7" ),
    "easy5" => array("3","7","4","6","8","2","9","1","5" ),
    "easy6" => array("9","5","1","7","4","3","6","2","8" ),
    "easy7" => array("5","1","9","3","2","6","8","7","4" ),
    "easy8" => array("2","4","8","9","5","7","1","3","6" ),
    "easy9" => array("7","6","3","4","1","8","2","5","9" )
);

if(isset($_POST['row'])){
    $easy = false;
    $client_responses = $_POST['row']; // EX: [" "," "," " ,"2","6"," " ,"7"," " ,"1"]
    $old = json_decode($_POST['old']);
    $old[] = $client_responses;
    // Or make    array_push($old,$client_responses);     if you prefere
    foreach ($good_answers as $easy => $responses) {
        if($client_responses === $responses){
            $easy = $responses;
            break;
        }
    }

    // generating table for HTML of client responses
    echo '<table>';
    // saving old responses
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. json_encode($old) .'" name="old">';
        foreach ($old as $number => $row) {
            echo '<tr id="row'. $number .'">';
            
            for ($i=0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
                echo '<td class="cellTop">';
                    echo '<input type="text" maxlength="1" name="row" value="'. $row[$i].'"/>';
                echo '</td>';
            }

            echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Hi! You can [flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20flag%3F,and%20the%20modal%20will%20appear.) as duplicate if you think that it already have an answer in SO.